# Search for Tree

Tags: c#, tree, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

Here is a search implementation for my tree.  It searches each node in a breadth-first manner first, but it goes deeper in a depth-first manner, in the event it needs to go deeper.  I know there may be multiple identical items in the tree (well, not my current use of it, but I still need to presume that), so it just returns the children for the first instance found.  If I ever have duplicate items with different children, there will be other things needing change anyway.

For reference, this method is being implemented as part of my tree here: [Trees and their uses](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84623/trees-and-their-uses)

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetChildren(T item)
{
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>> itemSet = items.Where(x => item.Equals(x.Value));

    if (itemSet.Count() != 0)
    {
        int index = itemSet.ElementAt(0).Key;

        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Tree<T>>> branchSet = branches.Where(x => x.Key == index);
        
        if (branchSet.Count() != 0)
        {
            return branchSet.ElementAt(0).Value.GetChildren();
        }
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Tree<T>> kvp in branches)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> coll = kvp.Value.GetChildren(item);

        if (coll != Enumerable.Empty<T>())
        {
            return coll;
        }
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

I'm sure there are ways I can improve this, although it looks good to me.

## Edit:

Some people asked me for clarification on how my search combined the breadth-first and depth-first searches in The 2nd Monitor.  Here are some images showing how they each work (the first two taken from Wikipedia):

#### Breadth-first search:

[image: Breadth First Search]

#### Depth-first search:

[image]

#### My search:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I would use `First()` instead of `ElementAt(0)` as it conveys the intention better.
2. Instead of using `something.Count() != 0` you should use `something.Any()`. This avoids having to iterate over the entire sequence just to find out if there are any items in it.
3. Also you are not interested in the entire `itemSet` you're just interested in the first one if it exists so you should make use of `FirstOrDefault` [which also provides a predicate overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549039%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
4. This `foreach` loop:

   > ```
   > foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Tree<T>> kvp in branches)
   > {
   >      IEnumerable<T> coll = kvp.Value.GetChildren(item);
   >
   >      if (coll != Enumerable.Empty<T>())
   >      {
   >          return coll;
   >      }
   > }
   > ```

   can be condensed to:

   ```
   var result = branches.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.GetChildren(item))
                        .FirstOrDefault(coll => coll != Enumerable.Empty<T>());
   return result ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
   ```

---

**Update**: Due to `KeyValuePair` being a value type to make it a bit neater a little helper is needed:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool EqualsDefault<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj, default(T));
    }
}
```

With this the method could be rewritten as:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetChildren(T item)
{
    var firstMatch = items.FirstOrDefault(x => item.Equals(x.Value));

    if (!firstMatch.EqualsDefault())
    {
        var branch = branches.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == firstMatch.Key);
        if (!branch.EqualsDefault())
        {
            return branch.Value.GetChildren(item);
        }
    }

    var result = branches.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.GetChildren(item))
                         .FirstOrDefault(coll => coll != Enumerable.Empty<T>());
    return result ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so that's how it would be done.

Comment: Using `FirstOrDefault` will not work, because it defaults to the first element.  Also, this wasn't stated in my question, but `items` is a `Dictionary`, and you cannot compare a `KeyValuePair` to `null`.

Comment: The top 4 items are helpful, and I have made the changes.

Comment: @Hosch: I fixed the `KeyValuePair` one. Regarding the `FirstOrDefault` - this is what your original code has been doing: First you filter with `Where`, then you check if you got any results and then you take the first one. Looks exactly like `FirstOrDefault` to me.

Comment: OK, I will check it again.

Answer (score 4):

Prefer positive boolean expressions over negations whenever possible.

> ```
> if (branchSet.Count() != 0)
> ```

This can be stated positively like this.

```
if (brancheSet.Any())
```

---

I've got to admit that I don't understand what this line does.

> ```
> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>> itemSet = items.Where(x => item.Equals(x.Value));
> ```

You're returning the `item` that you passed in as an argument to begin with? I guess it also returns other items that match the arg as well. It's not as immediately obvious as it could be. Consider the Linq query here.

> ```
> items.Where(x => item.Equals(x.Value));
> ```

It's a touch convoluted because I would expect `item` to be a member of `items`, but it's not. It's the method'd argument. I think some careful renaming and perhaps a comment will help here.

---

I'm convinced that your `for each` loop could be simplified with some Linq, but I've not quite worked out exactly how yet.

Something like this maybe.

```
return branches.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.GetChildren(item)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No, I am not returning `item`, I am returning all values in `itemSet` where `x.Value == item`.

Comment: I know. I was exaggerating a bit to make a point. `item` and `items` differ by one letter, but they're unrelated really. It causes more confusion than is necessary.